# numpy subscripting slower than python?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have just begun looking at numpy to speed up extraction of data from a PIL image.

It is clear that when you can use the numpy operator, it compares very favorably to normal python code (about 200 times faster in my benchmark).

I anticipated that subscripting would also be faster on a numpy array than on a Python list, but I am finding it is about 2 x slower. I could understand it being the same, but it being slower makes me think I am doing something wrong.

Are there artifacts in this benchmark

```
import timeit

setup = '''
import numpy
import random

asize = 1000
itrbl = [random.random() for i in range(asize)]
alist = itrbl
npa = numpy.fromiter(itrbl, numpy.float)
'''

np_operator='''
x = npa * 100
'''
np_subscr='''
x = [npa[i]*100 for i in numpy.arange(len(npa))]
'''
pyth_subscr='''
x = [alist[i]*100 for i in range(len(alist))]
'''


print 'numpy  operator    ', min(timeit.repeat(np_operator, setup, number=1000, repeat=3))
print 'numpy  subscripting', min(timeit.repeat(np_subscr,   setup, number=1000, repeat=3))
print 'python subscripting', min(timeit.repeat(pyth_subscr, setup, number=1000, repeat=3))
```

Comment: Why are you also comparing `numpy.arange` to `range`? Use `range` for both if you’re benchmarking subscripting.

Comment: as an aside, you don't need to use `np.fromiter`, you can just pass the list directly to `np.array`

Comment: But yeah, likely you are seeing the effect of essentially "boxing", `numpy` arrrays are essentially object-oriented wrappers around primitive, multidimensional arrays. All values in Python are full-fledged objects, even things like `int` and `float`, check out `import sys;  print(sys.getsizeof(100))`. So when you access a value from a numpy array it creates a new object each time, i.e. "boxes" the value in, say, a `np.int64` object.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan for noting the discrepancy. I started out using range in both but tried arange while I was fiddling. Going back to range makes a slight improvement but regular python subscripting is still twice as fast as numpy subscripting.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for explaining what's happening. It's clear that the lesson is not to use numpy UNLESS I can use a numpy operator. If you would like to add that information as a response, rather than a comment, I'd be glad to check it so you get the reputation points.

Also, thanks for the tip in .array vs .fromiter.